# adding elements to an ArrayList using a loop and outputting them on console

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I know this is a basic question but I've been struggling with with for many days and cannot find a solution.  Please, any advice would be very sincerely appreciated.

I'm simply trying to add elements (Node objects) contained in an existing ArrayList to a new empty ArrayList.  The idea is that if I can add the elements one at a time I can run a heap sort method on a list of 1 element, then on a list of 2, then on a list of 3, etc.

However when using a for loop, or a while loop, or even an enhanced for loop I cannot successfully add elements and output their resulting values or their order.  When I add them manually as follows it appears to work:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> test_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

test_list.add(0, 5);
test_list.add(1,10);
test_list.add(2, 15);
test_list.add(3, 20);
test_list.add(4, 25);

for (Integer num : test_list){      
System.out.println("output testing output testing" + num);
}
```

However, when I attempt to use a loop to add them such as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<test_list.size()-1; i++)
{
    test_list.add(i, i*5);
    System.out.println(test_list.get(i));
}
```

It will not work!  I've looked the the API for ArrayList and I've looked at stackoverflow questions, and from what I gather, the '.set(index, element)' method doesn't work on empty lists, however the '.add(index, element)' should work and I cannot figure out why it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your array list is empty (size = 0) before you start adding to it; So your loop is running on empty.

Enhanced for-loop will also not work because the list has no items in the first place.

When you add them manually, you successfully get items into the list because you were not depending on the size of the list.

Make use of the alternate implementation in [`Mert Ozdal's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506320/2089675)

Answer (score 1):

test_list.size() is Zero in your loop.  You need to specify the number of steps the for loops

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code with an empty list your for loop will not run at all. If you add more than 2 items outside the loop the for loop will work and your code will cause an infinite loop since your upper bound is test_list ArrayList's size and you are adding items to that object inside the for loop. Determine a static upper bound and populate your ArrayList that many times to avoid that infinite loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    test_list.add(i, i*5);
    System.out.println(test_list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: There is no infinite loop. Infact there is no loop. Your other suggestion to use a static upperbound is good though

Comment: Yes I realized that and edited my answer accordingly, thanks:)

Comment: There is also no runtime error. The loop will simply fizzle out of existence because the condition is false from the start

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.set(index, data)`

This is used to set an Item at a specified index. However if the list size is smaller than index you are trying to access, it will throw an exception, and it makes sense too. Set method should only be used to replace items and not to add items

`ArrayList.add(index, data)`

This method is used to insert some data in the list. If the you are trying the insert something in the middle of the list, the data will be adjusted to make room for the new index. If you are trying to add something at the end of the list, that would also work fine. But if the index that you are trying to add the item is greater than the size of the arrayList, this method will IOB exception as well.